# Different .phtml file

Tags: magento2

I have following problem: In my case i have to override my `grouped.phtml` file BUT not for every group product. Is it possible to have multiple `grouped.phtml` files and that i can choose witch of them should be loaded for witch site?

Comment: please check in which layout you override.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
You have to extend \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped and insert your conditions in the **setTemplate** method.

**Block: app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Type/Grouped.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Type;

/**
 * Class Grouped
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Type
 */
class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
{
    /**
     * @param string $template
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView
     */
    public function setTemplate($template)
    {
        $contition = 'something';
        if ($contition == 'test'){
            $template = "Vendor_Module::product/view/type/grouped-test.phtml";
        }

        if ($contition == 'hello'){
            $template = "Vendor_Module::product/view/type/grouped-hello.phtml";
        }
        return parent::setTemplate($template);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Than create template files:
**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped-test.phtml**
**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped-hello.phtml**

Or you can also create a plugin method for setTemplate without editing the layout file and set your custom template on afterSetTemplate.
You can find more information about plugins here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you i will test it out

Comment: could you provide me the paths where i should put it?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you don't know how to create a custom module you can take a look here: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: well, somehow i get an 404 cant find cant find that page